# Get Azure AD User Roles In PHP

Tags: php, azure, authentication, active-directory

I have a small application I am writing in PHP where I need to check if a given user has a given role assigned to them. I am using Azure App Service with app service authentication enabled to authenticate users against the azure active directory. As part of the application I need to get the users username, display name, and if they are a member of one or more of three security groups which they could be a part of to define what access levels they have within the application.

I need to do it this way as I can't have the roles managed within the application, instead it needs to be managed through active directory security groups. I am seeking a method that is native to azure app service (as in ideally not doing a separate LDAP lookup if possible). I know how to extract the authenticated username from the header data sent to the application (`HTTP_X_MS_CLIENT_PRINCIPAL_NAME`) however I don't know how I can get the full display name and how to check if a user has specific roles assigned to them. I have already output a copy of the entire php `$_SERVER` super global array to see if the data I am seeking is in there but I can't find it in there.

For the purposes of this question make the following assumptions...

user1@domain.com is assigned the roles role1, role2, role3
user2@domain.com is assigned the role role3 only

So if either user logs in I need to be able to show their full name based on their AD entry and need to be able to check if they are part of security groups `role1` `role2` and/or `role3`.

I would post an example of my code but I have no idea where to start with getting this data so the only code I have thus far is a test block to print all the `$_SERVER` values onto the page for testing purposes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can leverage [Microsoft Graph REST APIs](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/) yo achieve your requirement.

First of all, you can follow https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only to implement the functionality to acquire access token in app only way, then you can make a HTTP request of [List memberOf](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_memberof) to get groups and directory roles that the user is a direct member of.

The HTTP GET url should be like `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{HTTP_X_MS_CLIENT_PRINCIPAL_NAME you get from header}/memberOf`, and set the access token you get above in the `authorization` header.

Furthermore, you can refer to https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-php-graphapi-directoryextensions-web/blob/master/AuthorizationHelperForGraph.php the sample for how acquire the access token in app only.